# Where to start in PHP for a script that rearranges tab delimited data

Tags: php, tabs, delimited

This would be one of my first PHP projects.

Where to start in PHP for a script that rearranges tab delimited data.

I have a tab delimited data text file that needs to be rearranged periodically. Some entire columns would have to move to different parts of the text file, and some headers of columns need to be renamed as well. Basically my tab delimited data file is being converted to match another tab delimited data set to fit a system. (Actually the file is an Amazon.com SELLER CENTRAL Order Reports tab delimited text file that is in a different format from tab delimited text files downloaded from Amazon.com's own MARKETPLACE Order Reports)

I hope someone can give me some direction as to where I would start writing code or how to make this script work...

Answer (score 3):

You can read in the TSV file using PHP's [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), using `"\t"` as the delimiter.

This gives you an array of columns that you can manipulate as you require. Once done, you can then write the array as a line in a new file using [`fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

**Edit:** As an example, the process would go something like

1. Open file handles (using `fopen()`) to your existing data file (source) and the new destination file
2. Read in the source file line-by-line using `fgetcsv()`
3. Create a new array of columns using the values returned by `fgetcsv()` in the order required
4. Write the new array to the new file using `fputcsv()`
5. Once done, close both file handles

Comment: Well I didn't know that +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Parse the data using [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and use [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). If you need an example, there's one available on the multisort manual page.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have to know here

1. To match the TAB inside php you use the string: "\t"
2. Next you will need the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to obtain the array from one row of the file
3. next you'll need [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) cycling among the array elements to analyse the data
4. of course the [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP will always help you
5. and at the end when you'll need produce the final TAB delimited file you'll need the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Of course take a look at [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) and [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) functions in PHP.